# How to call property we just defined from the first request to use in the next request jmeter?

Tags: xml, soap, groovy, jmeter

I use config element "Property File Reader" to store the variables, so it can be accessed by all requests. I named the file variables.txt, we can see the first variable defined is "name":

[image]

and the second and third variable will be defined after first request is executed:

[image]

I successfully call the first variable:

```
${__P(name)}
```

but failed to call the second and third variable:

```
${__P(npwp1)}

${__P(npwp2)}
```

it always has a value 00:

[image]

and this is my jmx:

[image]

Actually how to call the second and the third variable in SOAP/XML-RPC Request?

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't expect Property File Reader to return latest/updated file,

It's a config element which is loaded once:

`PropertyReader` extends `ConfigTestElement` and according to [java docs](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/config/ConfigTestElement.html):

> expectsModification() If your config element expects to be modified in
>   the process of a test run, and you want those modifications to carry
>   over from sample to sample (as in a cookie manager - you want to save
>   all cookies that get set throughout the test), then return true for
>   this method.

`PropertyReader` doesn't define `expectsModification()` and therefore its properties are loaded once on startup and aren't refreshed after.

You can use [__setProperty](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) to set new properties inside Test

Finally ensure you understand the differences between properties and variables which you are mixing:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html

Comment: Thank you @user7294900, I can set new properties using `__setProperty` but I can't still call the new properties in the second Thread, I use both `${__P(npwp)}` and `${__property(npwp)}`, it returns `npwp`, not the value of npwp. Please help.

Comment: You need to define ${__setProperty(npwp,${npwp},)} and then get property in second thread ${__property(npwp,,)}

Comment: I already define `${__setProperty(npwp,${npwp},)}` in the first thread and use `${__property(npwp,,)}` in the second thread but it still returns `npwp`, by the way, I use Sampler `SOAP/XML-RPC Request`.

Comment: Does ${__setProperty(npwp,"test",)} works? if it does than your variable npwp is just empty

Comment: Yes, `${__setProperty(npwp,"test",)}` it works, it return `"test"`, actually i use `npwp = vars.get('npwp')` to get the value, so when i use `${__setProperty(npwp,npwp,)}` in the first thread and `${__property(npwp,,)}` in the second thread, it always returns `npwp`. Please help.

Comment: In JSR Sampler you can use `props.put("npwp", vars.get("npwp"))`

Comment: thank you, it works, I change from `${__setProperty(npwp,${npwp},)}` to `${__setProperty(npwp,${__property(npwp)})};`, by the way, if I set the second thread group with `Number of Thread = 2`, how to get all the values that are from the same property? is it using `ForEach Controller` or just use `${__property(npwp)}`?

Comment: Please open a different question